# Find max value in nested list in R

Tags: r, list, loops, nested, nested-lists

I have a nested list as follows:

```
results <- list()
c <- 1
outcomes <- c("Value1", "Value2", "Value3")
values <- c(2, 11, 20)
for(i in outcomes){
  for(p in 1:length(values)){
    results[[c]]  <- c(outcomes[p], values[p])
    c <- c + 1
  }
}
results <- results[1:3]
>results
[[1]]
[1] "Value1" "2"     

[[2]]
[1] "Value2" "11"    

[[3]]
[1] "Value3" "20"
```

I want to find a way to return the pair that has the highest value as follows: `"Value3" "20"` 
How can I do this only using base r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can be helpful:

```
#Code
results[which(unlist(lapply(results,function(x) as.numeric(x[2])))==max(unlist(lapply(results,function(x) as.numeric(x[2])))))]
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Value3" "20"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can extract the second element in the `list`, `unlist`, convert it to `numeric` find the index of the max element with `which.max` to extract the `list`

```
results[which.max(as.numeric(unlist(sapply(results, `[`, 2))))]
#[[1]]
#[1] "Value3" "20"
```

---

Or slightly compact with

```
results[which.max(as.numeric(do.call(rbind, results)[,2]))]
#[[1]]
#[1] "Value3" "20"
```